# TypeError while following a tutorial

Tags: python

I am facing a problem trying to fetch API data and convert to CSV

I have successfully printed data, but when I add the lines of code to sort the data, I get this error

```
     for x in myjson['data']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Here is my full line of code.

```
from ast import In
from email.mime import application
from webbrowser import get
import requests
import csv

from requests.api import head

url = "https://api-devnet.magiceden.dev/v2/collections/runecible/activities?offset=0&limit=100"

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
response = requests.request("GET", url,headers=headers,data={})
myjson = response.json()
ourdata =[]

for x in myjson['data']:
    listing = [['collection'], ['price']]
    ourdata.append(listing)

print(ourdata)
```

Comment: `myjson['data']`: it seems like `myjson` is a list, so you can't use a string as an index.

Comment: The output of [your API](https://api-devnet.magiceden.dev/v2/collections/degods/activities?offset=0&limit=100) seems to be an empty list.

Comment: what tutorial do you follow? You could add link in question (not in comments). Maybe you made some mistake and now it doesn't work. OR maybe this tutorial is old and outdated.

Comment: maybe first check `print( myjson )` to see what you get. Maybe you get some message about problem with connection - and this may help you. Many APis needs first to register on web page to get `API KEY`

Comment: @furas I posted the wrong API in the original post.

Print( myjson ) works fine.

Comment: it seems you have typo in url - if I use `runcible` instead `runecible` then myjson has some data - but still in needs different code in `for`-loop. I found this name `runcible` in examples in documentation https://api.magiceden.dev/#31fe6d3b-80eb-4d78-8582-3e66eeb45c25

Comment: see your tutorial again - it uses different URL `api.coincap.io`. And different urls may send different data and it may need different code to display it.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is typo in url.

It has to be `runcible` instead of `runecible` (without `e` in `run-e-cible`)

See url in example in documentation:

https://api.magiceden.dev/#3a6c0dd2-067f-4686-9a8b-8994667f1b67

Other problem is that server sends data with different structure. It is NOT dictionary with `['data']` but it is list with many dictionares - and this need different code in `for`-loop.

---

Minimal working code.

I removed many elements because they are not needed.

```
import requests
import csv

url = "https://api-devnet.magiceden.dev/v2/collections/runcible/activities?offset=0&limit=100"

response = requests.get(url)

data = response.json()
print(data)

# --- 

ourdata = []

for item in data:
    ourdata.append( [item['collection'], item['price']] )

print(ourdata)

# ---

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as fh:   # some systems may need `newline=''` to write it correctly
    writer = csv.writer(fh)  
    writer.writerow(['collection', 'price']) # `writerow` without `s` to write one row (with headers)
    writer.writerows(ourdata)                # `writerows` with `s` to write many rows (with data)
```

---

**BTW:**

You can also run it as

```
url = "https://api-devnet.magiceden.dev/v2/collections/runcible/activities"

payload = {
    "offset": 0,
    "limit": 100,
}    

response = requests.get(url, params=payload)
```

---

**EDIT:**

To make sure (because in similar question this also made problem):

Url `api-devnet.` (`Devnet`) is for testing and it may have fake or outdated values.
If you will need real data then you will need to use url `api-mainnet.` (`Mainnet`).

Text from [documentation](https://api.magiceden.dev/):

```
Devnet: api-devnet.magiceden.dev/v2 - this uses a testing Solana cluster, the tokens are not real
Mainnet: api-mainnet.magiceden.dev/v2 - this uses the real Solana cluster, the tokens are real and this is consistent with the data seen on https://magiceden.io/
```

**BTW:** In documentation at the top you can select language - ie. `Python Requests` - and it will show all examples in this language. But some code can be reduced.